# Laravel 419 Error - VerifyCsrfToken issue

Tags: php, laravel, csrf-protection, laravel-middleware

I have multiple Laravel sites hosted on the same server. With the latest site I've created, the contact form refuses to submit without throwing a 419 error. I have set up the routing in my web.php file just like the other websites, which have live, working contact forms, and I'm generating and sending the token exactly the same way - with `{{ csrf_field() }}`.

I found an answer to a similar question stating that you can disable Csrf checking by adding entries to the `$except` array in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`. I have verified that this does indeed resolve the 419 error:

```
protected $except = [
    'contact',
    'contact*',
];
```

But of course I wish to keep the Csrf functionality, and I only updated the `$except` array for troubleshooting value.

Does anyone know what may be different about the new Laravel environment that would have this 419 behavior despite passing the generated token? I have tried updating a number of ENV settings and toggling different things, but nothing other than modifying the `$except` array has had any influence on the issue.

### Update

Since there has been a bit of discussion so far, I figured I'd provide some additional info and code.

First, this is an ajax form, but don't jump out of your seat just yet. I have been testing the form both with and without ajax. If I want to test with ajax, I just click the button that's hooked up to the jQuery listener. If not, I change or remove the button's ID, or run `$("#formName").submit();` in the console window.

The above (ajax, old-fashioned submit, and the jquery selector with `.submit();`) all result in the exact same response - a 419 error.

And for the sake of completeness, here's my ajax code which is working on all of the other websites I'm hosting. I define a postData array to keep it all tidy, and I added a `console.log()` statement directly after it to (again) confirm that token is generated just fine and is being passed correctly with the request.

```
var postData = {
            
    name: $("#name").val(),
    email: $("#email").val(),
    message: $("#message").val(),

    _token: $("input[name=_token]").val()

};

console.log(postData);


$.post("/contact", postData, function (data) {

...
```

Any ideas? Could there be a configuration issue with my ENV or another file?

### Progress Update!

Because the other sites are working just fine, I cloned an old site and simply overwrote the files that I changed for the new website, and bam! It's working now. Doing a little bit more digging, I ran `php artisan --version` on the cloned version of the site versus the non-working version, and here are the results:

> Working Version: Laravel Framework 5.7.3
>
> Non-working Version: Laravel Framework 5.7.9

Perhaps this is a bug with Laravel? Or perhaps some packages on my server are out of date and need to be updated to work with the new version of Laravel?

Comment: Asuming to the CSRF Verification i guess you have setup these routes in the web.php and not in the api.php?

Comment: Yes, in `web.php` I have the following two routes: `Route::get('/contact', 'ContactController@index');` and `Route::post('/contact', 'ContactController@contactSubmit');`

Comment: Are you seeing the `_token` value being sent to the POST route? `dd($request->all())` in the `contactSubmit` function and make sure it's being sent properly.

Comment: I added the `dd($request->all())` before posting this question, and on my local dev environment it shows the json output correctly, including `_token`. However, on the server, it will not even reach the `dd()` because it throws the 419 error before executing even the first line of code in the `contactSubmit()` method. But the other contact forms on the other sites hosted on my server work fine without any issue.

Comment: @Chad Do you see `_token` being sent with the request in your browser's web inspector's Network tab?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes I do. All form data is showing under Form Data in the `contact` request in the Network tab.

Comment: Could the tokens that are being generated be invalid? I tried re-generating the `APP_KEY` but that did not fix the issue. I also flushed/cleared all cache & etc. files, again to no avail.

Comment: I've updated the question - the Laravel versions are different. Anyone know what needs to change for the new Laravel version's Csrf token functionality to work properly?

Answer (score 4):

> TLDR: This post contains lots of potential issues and fixes; it is intended for those scouring for related bonus information when stuck.

I just encountered this error using Laravel Sanctum in what looks like improperly setup middleware. Sanctum uses the `auth:sanctum` middleware for the guard, which is some kind of extension of the `auth` guard of which Laravel uses as the default, but session is handled by the `web` middleware group.

I can't exactly verbalize some of this internal-Laravel stuff; I am more experienced with JavaScript than PHP at the moment.

In my `api.php` file, I had the login/register/logout routes, and in my `Kernel.php` file, I copied `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` from the web group into the api group.

I had to do that to fix my login unit test that was throwing an error about "Session store not on request". Copying that allowed me my `postJson` request to work in the unit test, but sometime later, I started seeing 419 CSRF error posting from the JavaScript app (which is bad because it worked fine earlier).

I started chasing some filesystem permission red-herring in the `/storage/framework/sessions` folder, but the issue wasn't that (for me).

I later figured out that with Laravel Sanctum and the default `AuthenticatesUsers` trait, you must use the `web` guard for auth, and the `auth:sanctum` middleware for protected routes. I was trying to use the `api` guard for auth routes and that was central to my 419 errors with the AuthenticatesUsers trait.

If anyone gets 419 while CSRF was working or should work, I recommend doing some `\Log::debug()` investigations at all the key points in your system where you need these to work:

```
Auth::check()

Auth::user()

Auth::logout()
```

If you get strange behaviour with those, based on my observations, there is something wrong with your config related to `sessions` or something wrong with your config related to `web`, `api` guards.

The guards have bearing on the `AuthManager` guard which maintains state over multiple requests and over multiple unit tests.

This is the best description I found, which took over a week for me to discover:

[Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::logout does not exist Laravel Passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57813795/method-illuminate-auth-requestguardlogout-does-not-exist-laravel-passport)

As a random final example, if your session is somehow generating the CSRF token using data from the `web` middleware group while your routes are set to use `api`, they may interpret the received CSRF incorrectly.

Besides that, open Chrome dev tools and goto the Applications tab, and look at the cookies. Make sure you have the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie as unsecure (ie: not httpOnly).

That will allow you to have an Axios request interceptor such as this:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

axios.interceptors.request.use(async (request) => {
    try {
        const csrf = Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
        request.withCredentials = true;

        if (csrf) {
            request.headers.common['XSRF-TOKEN'] = csrf;
        }

        return request;
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(`axios# Problem with request during pre-flight phase: ${err}.`);
    }
});
```

That is how my current Laravel/Vue SPA is working successfully.

In the past, I also used this technique here:

**app.blade.php** (root layout file, document head)

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**bootstrap.js** (or anywhere)

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

const token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

In my opinion, most problems will stem from an incorrect value in one or more of these files:

- `./.env`
- `./config/auth.php`
- `./config/session.php`

Pay close attention to stuff like SESSION_DOMAIN, SESSION_LIFETIME, and SESSION_DRIVER, and like I said, filesystem permissions.

Check your nginx `access.log` and/or `error.log` file; they might contain a hint.

Answer (score 2):

just found your issue on the framework repo.
It is not a laravel issue, your installation is missing write permissions on the storage folder, thus laravel can't write session, logs, etc.

You get a 419 error because you can't write to the files, thus you can't create a sessionn, thus you can't verify the csrf token.

Quick fix: `chmod -R 777 storage`

Right fix: move your installation to a folder where nginx/apache/your user can actually write.
If you are using nginx/apache, move you app there and give the right permissions on the project `(chown -R www-data: /path-to-project)`
If you are using php artisan serve, change it's permissions to your user: `chown -R $(whoami) /path-to-project`

You get it, let writers write and you're good.

Comment: I am using database driver and still have this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your domain in browser address bar does not match `domain` key in `config/session.php` config file or `SESSION_DOMAIN` in your env file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but the problem in my case was https. The form was on http page, but the action was on https. As a result, the session is different, which is causing the csrf error.

Answer (score 0):

run this command
php artisan key:generate

Answer (score 0):

I used the same app name for staging and prod, being staging a subdomain of prod. After changing name of app in staging it worked

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue, it turned out that our `sessions` table wasn't correct for the version of Laravel we were using. I'd recommend looking to see if it's being populated or remaining empty (like ours was).

If it's empty, even when you have people visiting the site, I'd say that's what the issue is.

(If you're not using a database to [store your sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session), obviously I'd suggest checking wherever you are instead.)