# Laravel 5.7 @csrf is not working after enabling HTTPS

Tags: php, laravel

Initially my laravel application was working on HTTP protocol, Then I changed the protocol to HTTPS.
Unfortunately now my application's login is not working now.it shows me **419 error, Sorry Your session expired**. I tried couple of solutions suggested.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/post-request-in-laravel-57-error-419-sorry-your-session-has-expired.

[Laravel 419 Error - VerifyCsrfToken issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764590/laravel-419-error-verifycsrftoken-issue)

[Post request in Laravel 5.7 --- Error - 419 Sorry, your session has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583886/post-request-in-laravel-5-7-error-419-sorry-your-session-has-expired).

But none of these solved my issue.

I am using **CRUDBOOSTER** plugin to manage login.

Routes.php.

```
/* ROUTER FOR WEB */
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'], 'prefix' => config('crudbooster.ADMIN_PATH'), 'namespace' => $namespace], function () {

    Route::post('unlock-screen', ['uses' => 'AdminController@postUnlockScreen', 'as' => 'postUnlockScreen']);
    Route::get('lock-screen', ['uses' => 'AdminController@getLockscreen', 'as' => 'getLockScreen']);
    Route::post('forgot', ['uses' => 'AdminController@postForgot', 'as' => 'postForgot']);
    Route::get('forgot', ['uses' => 'AdminController@getForgot', 'as' => 'getForgot']);
    Route::post('register', ['uses' => 'AdminController@postRegister', 'as' => 'postRegister']);
    Route::get('register', ['uses' => 'AdminController@getRegister', 'as' => 'getRegister']);
    Route::get('logout', ['uses' => 'AdminController@getLogout', 'as' => 'getLogout']);
    Route::post('login', ['uses' => 'AdminController@postLogin', 'as' => 'postLogin']);
    Route::get('login', ['uses' => 'AdminController@getLogin', 'as' => 'getLogin']);
});
```

My Form

```
 <form autocomplete='off' action="{{ route('postLogin') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/> -->
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input autocomplete='off' type="text" class="form-control" name='email' required placeholder="Email"/>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input autocomplete='off' type="password" class="form-control" name='password' required placeholder="Password"/>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px" class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-12'>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"><i class='fa fa-lock'></i> {{trans("crudbooster.button_sign_in")}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-12' align="center"><p style="padding:10px 0px 10px 0px">{{trans("crudbooster.text_forgot_password")}} <a
                            href='{{route("getForgot")}}'>{{trans("crudbooster.click_here")}}</a></p></div>
        </div>
    </form>.
```

And I attaching my error screen. 
[image: Error Screen]

can any one help me rid this issue.

Comment: On the generated html file does the csrf displays correctly?

Comment: In Http/Kernal.php protected `$middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [ \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,]` these two enabled ?

Comment: @Vidal Yes.it shows the hidden token.

Comment: @ViperTecPro by default \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class was commented and I enabled it.

Comment: Is it your url with `https://www.xyz....` or `https://xyz.....` ??

Comment: my url is with `https://subdomain.main.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can see the hidden CSRF HTML input field, clear the cached data:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

and regenerate a new key:

```
php artisan key:generate
```